# Error on dropping a user from Amazon Oracle RDS

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, drop

```
DROP USER APEX_040200 CASCADE

Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'RDSADMIN.RDS_DDL_TRIGGER2'
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-20900: DROP USER APEX_040200 not allowed.
ORA-06512: at "RDSADMIN.RDSADMIN_TRIGGER_UTIL", line 442
ORA-06512: at line 2
04088. 00000 - "error during execution of trigger '%s.%s'"
*Cause: A runtime error occurred during execution of a trigger.
*Action: Check the triggers which were involved in the operation.
```

Manually created user (APEX_040200), but now I'm not able to drop that user/schema.

[image: Error message in console]

Answer (score 0):

This error code:

```
ORA-20900: DROP USER APEX_040200 not allowed.
```

represents user-defined exception in trigger named `RDSADMIN.RDS_DDL_TRIGGER2` (user errors range is from -20000 to -20999). It means that *someone* (DBA? Amazon?) doesn't allow you to drop user. Is it only APEX_040200 or *any* user, depends on what code that trigger contains.

Comment: how to remove this user? any workaround??

Comment: None, unless you disable/drop that trigger.

Comment: we are not able to disable/drop that trigger as well.

Comment: Well, that's it, then. You can't drop it.

Comment: May be you need to raise a SR with AWS RDS support team.